# Carrierwave/fog are uploading files to S3, but the app is still trying to use the local path to access images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I know this is a broad question, and I'm biting off a little more than I can chew for a first stab at a rails app, but here I am.

I tried to add an image upload/crop to a basic status app. It was working just fine uploading the images and cropping them with carrierwave, but as soon as I started using Fog to upload to S3, I ran into issues.

The image, and it's different sizes, appear to be ending up on S3 just fine, but the app is still trying to access the image as "/assets/uploads/entry/image/65/large_IMG_0035.jpg"

Locally, it just shows a broken image, but on Heroku it breaks the whole thing because

ActionView::Template::Error (uploads/entry/image/1/large_IMG_0035.jpg isn't precompiled

The heroku error makes sense to me because it shouldn't be there. I've combed through the app but don't know what's forcing this. I'll post any code anybody thinks will work? Thanks in advance!

**Clarification:**

Just to clarify, the images are uploading to S3 fine, the problem is how the app is trying to display the image_url

The app is using a local path in the asset pipeline, not the S3 path that it's actually uploading to.

Comment: how are you calling the image from your app?

Comment: `<%= image_tag @entry.image.url(:large), id: "cropbox" %> ` is how I'm calling it in the crop function right after it is uploaded

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. In my Carrierwave Initializer I was setting `host` to `s3.amazonaws.com` but when I removed that line altogether urls started working.

I hope this helps you resolve your issue, I fought this for several hours!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is related to how you are accessing your image in your view.

If you have mounted an uploader on the field avatar in the following manner:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

You would access it in your ERB as follows:

```
 <%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) %>
```

I would also suggest watching the following Railscast on the topic.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Comment: Thanks for the input, Kyle. It was actually built from that Railscast and from the one available to Pro accounts. I've tried your solution, but it's still calling /assets/uploads/entry/image/65/large_IMG_0035.jpg on the following page with `class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader end` and then using the ERB `<%= image_tag(@entry.image_url) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading issue, I bet it has to do with Carrierwave using Herkou.

Give this a glance and see if it helps.

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku

Comment: It's not just a Heroku issue, because when running locally, it's still trying to show the path as /assets/uploads/entry/image/65/large_IMG_0035.jpg

Answer (score -3):

I am not clear what exactly do you want to achieve.
But for now I have 2 ideas:

1. For assets host in CDN, you can take a look at this:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31
2. If you want the images to be part of a model-relation, here's my rough idea:
   Put the images path in a table column.
   For further information about this you can browse carrierwave github site.(It has many docs and tutorial)